# Alphabetically sort in new mongo db query command

Tags: php, mongodb

I try to solved alphabetically sort using new MongoDB manager using command aggregation pipeline

below are my code:

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");

$pipeline = [
            [ '$match' => ['listingStatus' => ''] ],
            [ '$group' => ['_id' => '$listingParticipants.email'] ],
            [ '$limit' => 10 ],
            [ '$skip' => 0],
            [ '$sort' => ['listingParticipants.firstName' => 1]]
        ];

       $aggregate = new \MongoDB\Driver\Command([
           'aggregate' => 'Test_collection',
           'pipeline' => $pipeline,
           'cursor' => new stdClass
        ]);

       $cursor = $manager->executeCommand('test_database', $aggregate);
```

in above code i use sort in pipeline with my string data type name field but it's not working properly so please write my code to solve this issue.

Comment: You are sorting after grouping and I don't think you're getting listingParticipants.firstName key till $sort aggregate pipeline that's why it's not sorting

Comment: Thanks.. it's Working. am applying sorting before grouping so in this situation it is working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, in a `$group` stage there is no name field that you are using for sort,

Better would be to `sort` after `group`

**add** `listingParticipants.firstName` in $group stage,

**Also Note:**

> **Mongo can not sort case-sensitive**

meaning --  for the names like Abcd, ABcd, abcd, Bacd, bxyz

the sorted result will be (if sorted in ascending order).

Abcd, ABcd, Bacd, abcd, bxyz.

I suggest you add a new field `sortName` for the name with `$toUpper` or `$toLower` operator,

```
sortName: {$toUpper: "$name"}
```

and then **use `sortName` for sorting**.

Comment: Is this ordering changed with new version of mongo driver?